# ¿Cómo puedo ver información de cualquier librería de python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

He visto que `python` tiene muchas librerías, pero a la hora de buscar información sobre alguna de ellas es muy poca información la que he encontrado, me gustaría saber ¿cómo se puede ver la información detallada de cada librería? Muchas gracias por la atención prestada.

Comment: Que es exactamente "información detallada" para ti?

Answer (score 6):

Las librerías de python(y algunos otros lenguajes) por normativa deben tener documentación, en formato [docstring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docstring), y puedes acceder a esta documentacion ejecutando el comando [help](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/), 
Colocare un ejemplo a continuación:

```
import math
help(math)
```

Este comando es util si los repositorios cuentan con esta documentación, lo puedes ejecutar sin problema:

```
help(sum)
```

De hecho puedes sacarle el jugo al máximo y si te gusta documentar tus programas, mira este ejemplo:

```
"""
@author J.NavaRow
@description: servicio de lectura
"""
class Reader:

  def type(self):
    """ @metodo type no devuelve nada solo pass
    """
    pass


print("para que sirve el metodo type?")
help(Reader.type)
print("Que tendra la clase?")
help(Reader)
```

<sub>Este comando lo aprendi hace poco por [abulafia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/7123/abulafia) que tiene tiempo dominando el idioma parsel [Enlace del chat explicado por el maestro](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/51526489#51526489)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Existe una web llamada **https://pypi.org/** la cual tiene todas las librerías disponibles en Python. Allí puedes ver información **sobre cada una de ellas.**